# помогите исправить код в калькуляторе nasm

Tags: ассемблер, nasm

nasm компилятор выдает ошибку помогите,исправьте ошибку пожалуйста

```
PRINT_STRING aszPromptGET_
STRING Buffer,102 
PRINT_STRING aszResult
 PRINT_DEC 4, eax
```

выше строки компилятор NetBEans IDE 8.1 указывает на эти ошибки и отказывается компилировать

```
 %include        "io.inc"

section .data
        aszPrompt       db      'Expression: ', 0Dh, 0Ah, 0
        aszPressEnter   db      0Dh, 0Ah, 0Dh, 0Ah, "Press ENTER to exit", 0
        aszResult       db      10, 13, "Result of your equation is ", 0

        OpAdd           equ     '+'
        OpSub           equ     '-'
        OpMul           equ     '*'
        OpDiv           equ     '/'
        OpFactorial     equ     '!'

        AllowedChars:
        OpChars         db      '='
        BinaryOp        db      '+-*/'
        UnaryOp         db      '!'
        LenOpChars      equ     $-OpChars
                        db      '0123456789'
        LenAllowedChars equ     $-AllowedChars
section .bss
        MaxBufLen       equ     1024
        Buffer          resb    MaxBufLen
        BufLen          resd    1
        Result          resd    1
        Op1             resd    1
        Op2             resd    1
        Operation       resb    1

section .text
global  CMAIN
CMAIN:
        mov     ebp,    esp     ;добавлено IDE SASM: for correct debugging
        ;ввод строки с выражением для вычисления
        PRINT_STRING    aszPrompt
        GET_STRING      Buffer, 1024
        ;т.к. пользуемся библиотеками SASM, то длину введённой строки
        ;вычисляем после ввода строки
        lea     esi,    [Buffer]
        xor     ecx,    ecx
        dec     ecx
        dec     ecx
        .GetStrLen:
                inc     ecx
                lodsb
                test    al,     al
        jnz     .GetStrLen
        mov     [BufLen],       ecx
        ;обработка выражения во введённой строке
        mov     eax,    0
        mov     dword [Op1],    0
        mov     dword [Op2],    0
        mov     byte  [Operation],      OpAdd

        lea     esi,    [Buffer]
        mov     ecx,    [BufLen]
        .GetCmd:
                push    ecx
                lodsb
                ;проверка корректности введённых символов
                lea     edi,    [AllowedChars]
                mov     ecx,    LenAllowedChars
                repne   scasb
                jnz     .Next
        .ProcessChar:
                lea     edi,    [OpChars]
                mov     ecx,    LenOpChars
                repne   scasb
                jz      .DoOperation
        .TestDigits:
                ;введена цифра
                and     eax,    0FFh
                sub     al,     '0'
                mov     ebx,    [Op2]
                lea     eax,    [eax+8*ebx]
                lea     eax,    [eax+2*ebx]
                mov     [Op2],  eax

                pop     ecx
                push    ecx
                cmp     ecx,    1
                jne     .Next

        .DoOperation:
                ;если это унарная операция, то сначала выполнить её
                cmp     al,     [UnaryOp]
                jne     .CalcBinaryOp
        .CalcUnaryOp:
                call    UnaryOperation
        .CalcBinaryOp:
                ;завершается предыдущая бинарная операция
                call    BinaryOperation
                ;проверка, что текущая операция - "завершение вычислений"
                cmp     al,     '='
                jne     .Next
                pop     ecx
                jmp     .Break
        .Next:
                pop     ecx
        loop    .GetCmd
.Break:
ResultShow:
        ;вывод результата
        PRINT_STRING    aszResult
        mov     eax,    [Op1]
        PRINT_DEC       4, eax
        ;завершение программы
        xor eax, eax
        ret

UnaryOperation:
                push    eax
                mov     ebx,    [Op2]
                cmp     al,     OpFactorial
                jne     .Calc
        .Factorial:
                cmp     ebx,    1       ;если операнд (ebx) равен 0, то ebx:=1
                adc     ebx,    0
                mov     eax,    1
                .FactMul:
                        mul     ebx
                        dec     ebx
                jnz     .FactMul
                jmp     .Calc
        .Calc:
                mov     [Op2],  eax
                pop     eax
        ret

BinaryOperation:
                mov     eax,    [Op1]
                cdq
                mov     ebx,    [Op2]
                cmp     byte [Operation],       OpAdd
                jne     .Sub
                add     eax,    ebx
                jmp     .Calc
        .Sub:
                cmp     byte [Operation],       OpSub
                jne     .Mul
                sub     eax,    ebx
                jmp     .Calc
        .Mul:
                cmp     byte [Operation],       OpMul
                jne     .Div
                mul     ebx
        .Div:
                cmp     byte [Operation],       OpDiv
                jne     .Calc
                idiv    ebx
        .Calc:
                mov     [Op1],  eax
                mov     dword [Op2],    0
                mov     al,     [esi-1]
                mov     [Operation],    al
        ret
```

Comment: Какую ошибку? Можно полное описание ошибки, а то в голове так сразу и не скомпилируешь....

Comment: PRINT_STRING ,aszPromptGET_STRING      Buffer, 102, PRINT_STRING    aszResult, PRINT_DEC       4, eax
компилятор NetBEans IDE 8.1 указывает на эти ошибки и отказывается компилировать

Comment: Лучше впиши в вопрос.

Comment: Ты бы как-то указал, что те четыре строки - это строки, на которые ругается компилятор. Вообщем парочка строк похожа на вызовы функций. Вот только обычно вызовы осуществляются командами call и invoke. К сожалению я не знаком с NASM, какой-то другой учил.